# warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted On branch master Untracked files:

Tags: git

Im new to git so sorry about this
Im trying to git commit -m " " and when I do it says:

```
warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted
On branch master
Untracked files:
nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you add a repo in the root of your home directory?

Comment: That is actually the most common way I've seen this error happen. Usually it's somebody new to Git who accidentally initializes a repo in their home directory. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

While I'd agree that "Git requires some caution", this is a common problem and error and is not difficult at all to fix in most circumstances. In fact, I just fixed this issue on a colleague's rig. Usually it is caused when someone new or not very knowledgeable about Git accidentally runs `git init` in their home directory, which initializes a Git repository in their home directory (which of course, you should never do).

The way to fix this is to `cd` to your home directory and then delete the `.git` directory by running:

`rm -rf .git`

(Note: make absolutely sure that when you run the above command, you are careful to add the `.git` to the end of the one-liner and you're not logged in as superuser, e.g. do not use `sudo`).

Then, double-check that the `.git` directory is removed by running `ls -a`. You shouldn't see it listed anymore.

Your home directory is now no longer a Git repository.

Answer (score -1):

I think a lot of work has to be done to fix this. Git requires some caution and care.

1. Have you actually initialized git repository in a CURRENT dirrectory? `git status` or `git whatchanged` may be helpful.
2. Before comitting you should add files, especially when you have "nothing added to commit but untracked files present"
3. Do you have actual permissions for read and write in your directory?

Check these points and you can eventually fix this